# Moving large amount of files (~ 100 000)

Tags: nautilus, transfer, batch

I work with folders that contain a lot of files, like 100 000 or even 1 000 000 files per folder. When I try to move the content of a folder into another, my computer always gets stuck. Even when the process seems finished, I can't see the content of any folder because nautilus seems completely frozen and I have to force my computer to restart. I noticed that this happens also when I try to move like 10 000 files.

Is that a problem of my computer or is it normal when working with these numbers?

Any smart way of performing this file transfer?

Comment: What about using the terminal (`cp -R SRC/ DEST/`)

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: Depending on the files cp -a could be better because it preserves owners, timestamps and permissions. I’d also recommend rsync because it can verify transfers and only copies files which don’t exist already.

Comment: Update: `gvfs-copy` (from the `gvfs-bin` package) can be faster than `cp`.

Comment: You have two questions here instead of one. Please check the [How To Ask](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page for instructions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps consider using a pure command line method to transfer very large amounts files, you will undoubtedly find the process is *substantially* faster than using a gui.

There are many different ways to accomplish this, but the following worked quickly, safely and efficiently on my system:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t <destination>
```

Some explanation for this command:

1. Your input directory is the '.' character and for this particular command you need to be in that directory
2. Your output directory is the `<destination>` in my example. Obviously modify this to suit your own needs and leave out the brackets.
3. This syntax allows for filenames with spaces as a bonus :)

Endless permutations are possible but this should work well and *much more efficiently* than the gui. One permutation for example: if you wanted to move *only* pdf files you could run:

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t <destination>
```

Use of `xargs` opens many possibilities particularly with the movement of such a large number of files. Many, many possibilities....

**Potential Problems:**

There are at least 2 potential pitfalls to ponder, thanks to the commenters below for these thoughts:

1. Your destination directory could be corrupt, in a subsequently unreachable location, mistyped etc. `mv` will still move the files there! Be careful here...
2. If the `-t` option (`--target-directory`) is missing and the destination folder is actually a file you will move one file and fail on the rest. `mv` has 2 uses: *rename* source to destination or *move* source to *directory*. Again be careful...

Comment: Wouldn't just `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t test {} +` do?

Comment: @muru: Thanks for that,  I have trimmed to extraneous `-name...` piece but I have left `xargs` in place.

Comment: I don't know... While the command is obviously correct as it stands, I would consider a complete move a bit too error-prone. (What if you, for instance, forget to include the `-t` flag? I think all files would be "moved" to one single file called `test`, resulting in the loss of all your files except one.) I think I would prefer an `rsync` followed by, if all has gone right, a  `rm`. However, I can imagine scenarios where such a check can not be automated.

Comment: @Jos: Thanks, I have added a footer note describing this possibility. Nice to see an `rsync ` example written up as an answer?

Comment: Linux supports extremely long argument lists, so you can probably do `mv dir1/*  dir2`, and only resort to `find -exec` if there's a problem, or if you need to avoid matching folders with your glob.  (Although depending on your naming conventions, often `*.*` will match most files but not most directories, since it's common to have a `.extension` on files, and common not to have a `.` in directory names)

Answer (score 4):

I had similar experience before, it is normal when dealing with a large number of files. I was having a large collection of PDF data-sheets (electronic parts).

GUI tools check for some *file details & meta data* (Icon/Thumbnail, Size, ...), it will be a big deal in such case. Even in *Icon View* and without thumbnails, they will freeze as most of them are not designed for such extreme case. GUI tool try to load presentation icons for all files/folders in directory even those items are not visible to user in current screen portion. *Sorting* is also part of the problem and no way to avoid it.

- I end up splitting files files on separate folders based on brand/model less then 10000 each. May be you can use date (as most people do with photos/scans) or first letter(s) (as in [Ubuntu package repository](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/))
- It is easier to use CLI tools instead as they show only what you have requested. You can use `locate` for quick search in stead of `find`.
- For move operation, use `mv` in terminal (GUI tools are slow because they try to update the view periodically).

  If it is in the same partition, the command will change only the pointers in the File-system index. If not, then it will be dual operation (copy & delete). That will be expensive.

There is only one case I can help, If you are copying those files multiple times and they are not updated. As I did when I share my collection with friends, each time I try to copy it takes a decade. (This is more useful with small size files only)

- Create a single package or few packages, like zip with no/low compression. When you copy it, it will faster, so let [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) do its job.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a solution which gives you the benefits of the command-line operations with the GUI feeling and flexibility combined, I recommend `mc` ([**midnight commander**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander)).

[image: mc commander 2-pane view]

It is a ncurses-based visual file manager - you have a two-pane view on your files and a menu available. Use of the mouse is possible, even over ssh. You can browse around your fs, inspect files with the file viewer, filter according to criteria on-the-fly and have the copy or move operations done on the command line.

It's a clone of the DOS program [Norton commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander) which was popular in the mid-Eighties. It works well whenever the GUI starts to get unreliable for me, and ideal for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered somewhat similar problems - I was testing my RAID setup and when doing huge transfers (e.g. 100,000+ files and 1-2 TB of data in one go) it seems like transfers start fairly speedy - lets say ~200MB/sec, then quickly slow down to a reasonable plateau ~90-120MB/sec (possibly after consuming some flash cache storage on the drives). Then after 20-30min, the operation gradually starts to drop to a much lower plateau ~30-40MB/sec, worse when dealing with small files - taking a 4-5 hour operation closer to 15hours.

I spent some time trying to diagnose - e.g. possible drive faults. Despite trying different tools - command line, nautilus, I couldn't maintain a decent throughput for very large copy operations.

What worked best for me was to use midnight commander, and whenever copying got slow, I would pause the operation until the hard-drive light went out after any pending operations flushed out - usually a minute or so - then un-pause MC again and it would shoot back up to a decent pace for another 20-30min. Rather annoying though.